# How to give a lower bound for the blow up value of an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From *Nonlinear Dispersive Equations, Terence Tao*, page 18. Exercise 1.11.

Let $p>1$, let $\mathcal{D}$ be a finite dimensional normed vector space and let $F\in C^{0,1}_{loc}(\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{D})$ have at most $p$-th power growth, thus 
$$
|F(\mu)|_{\mathcal{D}}\le C_{\dim(\mathcal{D},p)}(1+|\mu|^{p}_{\mathcal{D}})
$$ for all $\mu\in \mathcal{D}$. Let $t_{0}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_0\in \mathcal{D}$, and let $u:(T_{-},T_{+})\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ to be the maximal classical solution to the Cauchy problem
$$
\mu(t_0)=\mu_0, \partial_{t}\mu(t)=F(\mu(t))
$$
given by the Picard theorem. Show that if $T_{+}$ is finite, then we have the lower bound
$$
|\mu|_{\mathcal{D}}\ge C_{p}(T_{+}-t)^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}
$$
as $t$ approaches $T_+$ from below, and similarly for $T_{-}$. Given an example to show that this blow up rate is best possible.

---

I want to ask for a hint because I do not know what is the right approach to attack this problem. For simplicity I assume $\mu>0$ and let $\dim(\mathcal{D})=1$ I have
$$
|F(\mu)|\le C_{p}(1+\mu^{p})
$$
But I still do not know how to bound $\mu$ from this. We have the crude estimate:
$$
\mu(t)\le \mu_0+C_{p}\int^{t}_{0}(1+\mu^{p}(s))ds=(\mu_0+C_p t)+C_p \int^{t}_{0}\mu^{p}(s)ds
$$
However, I do not know how to get any useful information from this estimate. For example, for simplicity assume $C_{p}=1$ and differentiate $(1+\mu^{p})$ we have
$$
\log(1+u^{p}(t))\le \log A+\int^{t}_{t_{0}}p\mu^{p-1}
$$
Therefore we have
$$
1+\mu^{p}\le Ae^{\int^{t}_{t_{0}}p\mu^{p-1}}
$$
which is not really better than the previous crude estimate. So I feel rather lost.

(I found this post [Estimating rate of blow up of an ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291678/estimating-rate-of-blow-up-of-an-ode?rq=1) to be very similar, so I need to read it carefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how to do the 1D problem.  So we have
$$ \frac{d\mu}{dt} = F(\mu) ,$$
with $|F(\mu)| \le C(1+|\mu|^p)$.  Divide both sides by $1+|\mu|^p$ to get
$$ \left| \frac d{dt} G(\mu) \right| \le C ,$$
where
$$ G(\mu) = \int_0^\mu \frac{dm}{1+|m|^p} .$$
Integrate both sides from $t=t$ to $t=T^+$ to get
$$ \int_{\mu(t)}^\infty \frac{dm}{1+|m|^p} \le C (T_+ - t) , \quad (\text{for $t < T_+$}) $$
Note that if $\mu$ is larger than $1$ (which we are allowed to assume because we may suppose that $t$ is sufficiently close to $T_+$), then
$$ \int_{\mu(t)}^\infty \frac{dm}{1+|m|^p} \ge \frac12\int_{\mu(t)}^\infty \frac{dm}{m^p} = \frac1{2(p-1)} [\mu(t)]^{-(p-1)} .$$
Go from there.

(Basically I am mimicking a proof of Gronwall's Theorem.)

Comment: Yes, this is in the section of Gronwall's Theorem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution works only when $\mu$ is real-valued. How should I do in the general vector-valued case?

Comment: You could use the inequality $d|\mu|/dt \le |d\mu/dt|$.  You might have to be a little careful if one ever has $\mu(t) = 0$, but I don't think it will be a serious problem.