# An attractor for blow-up solutions to a cubic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

(Related to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/317353/13042)).

Consider the nonlinear ODE 
$$\tag{1}
\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+u=u^3, \qquad t\in\mathbb R,$$
which has the conserved quantity 
$$\tag{2}
E=\frac12 u'^2+\frac12 u^2 -\frac14u^4.$$ 
Consider only these solutions that satisfy $u>0$ and $u'>0$.

I am interested in solutions that blow-up at time $T$, in the sense that 
$$
\lim_{t \nearrow T} u(t)=+\infty.$$ 
The following family describes all solutions with $E=0$, parametrized by the blow-up time;
$$
u_{0, T}(t):=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sin(T-t)}.$$
The phase portrait suggests that the trajectories of these solutions are an attractor for (1);[image: PhasePortrait]

and this is reasonable, because (2) yields 
$$
u'=\sqrt{2E -u^2 + \frac12u^4} = \frac{u^2}{\sqrt2} + O(1), $$
so when $u$ is very big I expect $u$ to be indistinguishable from the unique solution to 
$v'=\frac{v^2}{\sqrt 2} $ that blows up at $T$, that is, $$v_T(t)=\frac{\sqrt2}{T-t}, $$
and $v_T$ is asymptotically equivalent to $u_{0, T}$ as $t\nearrow T$.

I would like to obtain a more precise, quantitative version of this attraction.

> **Question**. Let $u$ be a solution to (1) such that $u(t)\to +\infty$ as $t\nearrow T$. Is it true that $$|u(t)-u_{0, T}(t)|\to 0,\qquad \text{as }t\nearrow T?$$ Is it true that $$\frac{u(t)}{u_{0,T}(t)}\to 1,\qquad \text{as }t\nearrow T?$$

*Remark*. The equation (1) is a special case of [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation).

Comment: This equation has an exact set of solutions using the Jacobi elliptic function $\operatorname{dn}$.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you, that looks useful. Unfortunately, I don't know a word about these functions. As far as I understand from skimming some references, such as [this book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/The+Duffing+Equation%3A+Nonlinear+Oscillators+and+their+Behaviour-p-9780470715499) (Kolvalcic-Brennan (eds), "The Duffing equation"), the Jacobi elliptic functions describe the *periodic* solutions, that is, those that do not blow up. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right. These are periodical solutions. A prototypical one is given by the solution of the pendulum equation. The $\operatorname{dn}$ never becomes zero.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291678/8157) is related to the present one.